# Trigger MySQL don't work

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

```
USE `db`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `recintos_BDEL` 
BEFORE DELETE ON recintos 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DELETE FROM imagenes WHERE id_imagen IN (
    SELECT imagenes_id_imagen FROM r_imagenes_recintos 
    WHERE recintos_id_recinto=OLD.id_recinto
    );
END; $$
DELIMITER |
```

OR

```
USE `db`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `recintos_BDEL` 
BEFORE DELETE ON recintos 
FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM imagenes WHERE id_imagen IN (
    SELECT imagenes_id_imagen FROM r_imagenes_recintos 
    WHERE recintos_id_recinto=NEW.id_recinto
);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference appears to be the use of a `BEGIN ... END` compound statement block in the first instance (and an erroneous change of / missing closing delimiter in the second instance).

Since the trigger only contains a single statement, there is no *need* for a `BEGIN ... END` compound statement block—but it certainly causes no harm.  That is to say, with corrected use of statement delimiters, both approaches will achieve the same outcome.

For what it's worth, my own personal preference would be to use the second instance (i.e. avoid compound statement blocks where they are not strictly necessary).